# Chern class of $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2 \# 6\overline{\mathbb C\mathbb P^2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I would like to compute the first Chern class of $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2 \# 6\overline{\mathbb C\mathbb P^2}$ in terms of the generators of $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2$ and $\overline{\mathbb C\mathbb P^2}$. I tried to use the Hirzebruch signature formula but without success, since the resulting equation permits more than one solution (this is fairly doable for the case $\mathbb C\mathbb P^2 \# \overline{\mathbb C\mathbb P^2}$)

Comment: There is a formula for the Chern class of a blowup. Ultimately you should get $(3,-1,-1,\dots,-1)$.

Comment: Thank you, although I wanted a more algebraic geometric argument. But that is good enough. Do you mind to tell me a good reference to that formula?

Comment: Unfortunately not; I don't know much complex geometry and learned it from personal communication. I think the way you prove the formula is algebro-geometric.

Comment: Such things are done in detail in Griffiths and Harris. In greater generality, see I. Porteous, "Blowing up Chern classes," Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc., 56:118-124, 1960.